# Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

When I clicked on the touchableopacity button to navigate to another screen within the same tab I got this warning and i cannot navigate. When I run I see the navigated page on my screen but on pressing tab redirects me to the same tab and still, the buttons don't work

I made stack navigator and tab navigator and merged both of them. but using `this.props.navigation.navigate("checkout")` don't work

```
<View style={{ flexDirection:'column', alignItems:'center' }}>
   <TouchableOpacity 
      activeOpacity = { .5 } 
      onPress{ this.props.navigation.navigate('CatWise') }
   >
      <Image style={{ height:35,width:35,resizeMode:"cover" }} source={ require('../assets/cat_image.png') }/>
      <Text>Electronics</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

I expect that after I click on that `TouchableOpacity` it should redirect me to the catwise screen. \

Warning:

```
Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your onPress function to this:

```
<TouchableOpacity 
    activeOpacity = { .5 } 
    onPress{() => this.props.navigation.navigate('CatWise') }
>
```

When you pass your function, it will be executed directly during the render, meaning that the result of the function execution will be passed to the onPress handler, and not the function itself